# How to find the fundamental set of solutions of a second order ODE with constant coefficients, when given the solution form.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Q:
By looking for solutions to
                                  $$y''' − y'' = 0$$
in the form $y = e^{rx}$, find a fundamental set of solutions to the above equation.

> A:
>   {$e^0$, $xe^0$, $e^x$} forms the fundamental set of solutions

What is the full methodology which gains you this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substitute *y=e<sup>rx</sup>* in the equation: *y'''- y''= 0*. This gives the following:

*(e<sup>rx</sup>)''' - (e<sup>rx</sup>)'' = 0*

The derivatives of an exponential function is this exponential function times the constant term in the exponent:

*(e<sup>rx</sup>)' = re<sup>rx</sup>*

Thus the above equation is equal to:

*r<sup>3</sup>e<sup>rx</sup> - r<sup>2</sup>e<sup>rx</sup> = 0*

*(r<sup>3</sup> - r<sup>2</sup>)e<sup>rx</sup> = 0*

*r<sup>2</sup>(r - 1)e<sup>rx</sup> = 0*

This means that *r=1* or *r=0* are solutions to the equation: *y'''- y''= 0*